# Looping through parameters from the mapping table (PYTHON, DATA FRAME)

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have the following table which I am inserting as a pandas.dataframe:

```
A B 
1 4 
1 5 
2 4 
3 7
3 8
```

I would like to create the function in SQL which would go through the specific values of column 'A' and for them search for appropriate values from the column 'B' but not taking all of the possible combinations of A & B because of the size of dataset.

SQL Script below:

```
select
cust_id as customer_id,
cust_country_cd as customer_country,
income,
month,
year
from database1
where 
cust_id = '{values from column A}',
cust_country_cd = '{values from column B}'
```

How could I do it using for loop?

Comment: What is the expected output for your table? Could you please post it?

Comment: Expected output would be the database containing record for specific dates. I need to somehow use the values from column A and consecutive values from column B to build the query in SQL

Comment: Do you want to create a new table for each iteration in your database? Or do you want to have a Pandas DataFrame with the results of the query?

Comment: Pandas dataframe with the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
for i = 1 To range(df.shape[0])
  strQuery = """ select
        cust_id as customer_id,
cust_country_cd as customer_country,
income,
month,
year
from database1
where 
cust_id = '"""+ df.iloc[i]['A']+"""'
AND cust_country_cd  = '"""+ df.iloc[i]['B'] +"""'"""
```

And then you have to execute the query and fetch and structure the results.